# Access archived private messages using Facebook Graph API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

How can I access archived private messages using Facebook's Graph API?

`https://graph.facebook.com/me/inbox` seems to return unarchived messages only.

Comment: It takes nothing away from the validity of your question, but I find it scary that third-party apps can access private messages.

Comment: @zneak if you authorize them only! Without the `read_mailbox` permission there’s no access to your mailbox.

Comment: Fair enough. I'd have to seriously trust the developer to let that happen though ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So the deal (apparently) is that archived messages are simply not available VIA the api. Whether this is a bug or not is yet to be determined.

You can see this behavior by querying a specific message by it's ID in the [API Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer), then archiving the message through Facebook. Returning to the Explorer and querying the same message yeilds the uber generic and much despised `"Unsupported get request"`.

```
{
  "error": {
    "message": "Unsupported get request.", 
    "type": "GraphMethodException", 
    "code": 100
  }
}
```

Comment: Just reproduced that. Major bummer!

Comment: Apparently you can still access comments of an archived thread, but not the thread itself, what the heck!?

Comment: Well.. the docs only reference a users "inbox" and archived messages are not there... so that seem's logical. But if the comments to that thread are still available (with no context) I'd think there's a bug in there...